# Can't connect to cloned AWS machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, clone

I have an existing AWS virtual machine. I want to clone it and change the clone. The existing machine is accessible to anyone with http, https and ssh. I want the clone to be accessible as well.

I did the following to create the clone:

1. Stop the original VM.
2. Create an AMI image from the VM.
3. Start the original VM.
4. Create a VM from the new AMI image, making sure to choose the same Security Group and SSH key pair as the original VM.

The new VM is created, but I can't reach it. http, https and ssh all fail to connect (connection timed out).

Since the original instance is not Nitro based, I can't connect with the ec2 serial connection. There is nothing suspicious on the new machine's system log.

How can I clone a machine AND have it available?

Comment: That process will generally work. I often find that when these kinds of things happen it can be something simple I missed. I suggest you double check all the basics like NACL, security groups, routing, VPC, subnet, and see if you can ping it from the other instance. I'd also consider instance based firewalls, but it's probably not that. If you want further help I suggest you edit your post to include a lot of screenshots of details so we can help you spot the problem - EC2 instance screen with subnet / SG, SG rules, NACL, routing, etc.